# what is the preferred file type from which R should import data?

Tags: java, r, csv

I'm doing a course on algorithms and data-structures , and for my assignments , i am advised to do a lot of statistical tests before i submit them. My tests are mainly for execution times , randomness of generated output etc. I was looking at R for a pictorial representation of my data.

I would like to know what kind of files R *prefers* to read data from , and which of them can be easily created in java.

I saw a lot of people giving csv files to R , and for that i would need something like the openCSV library in java. Also , Compared to csv-s , how better/worse is a delim-separated .txt file for the same purpose?

**edit:** 
well , when i said *prefers* i really didn't personify R or anything... just i thought it'd be the best way to express what i felt. I read somewhere in R's page that excel sheets arent a good choice , especially  the one's from *post* office 2007. That coupled with the thought that *can life really be so easy?* , that i find the one *software* i'm looking for , and she accepts my humble tab separated text file and gives me back all that i ever wanted ? seemed too good to be true.

i thank everyone for their answers , R is impartial to data import file-types it seems.

Comment: R can read in almost any reasonable format.  CSV is a particularly easy format to read in but something like tab-delimited is very easy as well...

Comment: I would prefer a tab separated file. As it doesn't involve any additional libraries. any advantages/disadvantages in the text-csv input file types comparison ?
ps : why don't you put this in the "answer" part instead of as a comment. i can vote you up and mark it if my question is solved :)

Comment: Have a look at `?read.delim`

Comment: Here's a totally off-the-wall idea. Why not read the R Data Import/Export manual? http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html R doesn't "prefer" anything, in all my 20 years of using R and S it's still never shown enough sentience for a preference for anything.

Comment: Can you turn this question into a community wiki? R doesn't prefer a data type, but this thread can be a collection of answers on how to read certain formats. As pointed out by Spacedman, the manual is also a good choice to read.

Comment: @spacedman I have noticed that as of late R 3.0.1 seems to have developed an attraction for .RData.  I don't think they're in a committed relationship yet but let's keep an eye on this budding romance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that R does not really "prefer" anything. It's well suited to take care of many kinds of data formats.

- CSV files: `read.csv` or `read.csv2` depending on the separator your CSV file has.
- Delimited files: `read.delim` or `read.delim2` depending on what decimal separator you have. Here a tab is the default but could in principle be anything. Even a , or ;.
- Fixed width format files: `read.fwf` which also uses tab as the default separator.

That should give you some ideas.

Comment: Just for mentioning, if you need to import a file coming from other software format such as spss, stata, sas, then [`foreing` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html) is the way to go.

Comment: @Jilber you mipselled `foreign` there :-) .  BTW, there are quite a few `R` packages to read from other languages, not to mention from Excel or a variety of image file formats as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you have very big datasets, I would suggest using the SQL variant. With that you can really easy SELECTing the subsets. Of course, you have to convert it to a database format first, what can be accomplished by doing something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csvTest.csv'
INTO TABLE csvImport
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

(see http://code.dedu.ch/2011/07/csv-file-direkt-in-mysql-importieren/ , unfortunatly a german tutorial, but the code provided there should be enough.)

Edit: Forgot to enclose SQL Package link:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html

In all other cases, R doesn't prefer any data. You just have to configure the reading process correctly like the other people suggested.